# Storing Different Types of Questions and Answers in a Relational Database

Tags: python, database-design, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I have three types of questions:

1. Vocab (represented by `question:answer` pairs)
2. Grammar (represented by `question:[list, of, answers]`)
3. Listening (represented by `question:answer` --where value is an `.oog`/`.wav` audio file).

<sub>I avoided the term `key:value` here since I'm not sure dictionaries can store audio.</sub>

My question:

How can I model this set of tables into a manageable design?

```
languages         lessons        lesson_types
=========         ========       ============
lang_id           lesson_id      lt_id
lang_name         lang_id        lt_name
                  lesson_name    lt_desc
                  lt_id
```

And that's the simple part.

The part I am having trouble understanding is how I can serialize different types of objects in python to overcome the differences each type of question proposes. In a strict, DBMS-only approach, I would use a separate table for each type of question (since BLOBs hold audio, grammar questions can have upwards to a dozen parts to describe its tense, gender, etc). I'm excited to see what `sqlalchemy` is able to do in terms of simplifying a database's structure.

How can I go about designing a `questions` table that can handle dictionaries *as well* as serializable, `sqlite3`-friendly audio formats?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's wrong with a table Questions `(question_id, question_text)`, a table Answers `(question id, answer_text)`, and a table Audio_Answers `(question_id, audio_blob)`? (That is: Each Answer row contains *one* question id, and *one* answer. Where a question has multiple answers, there will be multiple entries the answer table for that question. This applies in the exact same way to the Audio_Answers table.)

That would allow you to model all three types of question with maximum flexibility. questions with a single or multiple answers can be handled in the exact same way. The two answers tables hold all of the answers, one answer per row.

Comment: Well then I should go with a table for `grammar_answers`, you think? I designed a prototype that skipped the database, and my biggest problem was comprehensive coverage of the various conjugations...I ended up with a list that kept gaining more and more `Null` parts as I explored more ways to use the same verbs.

Comment: @Droogans: No, the point of this structure is that questions with a single or multiple answers can be handled in the exact same way. The two answers tables hold all of the answers.

Comment: So, a character-delimited value list goes into the same answer table that simple vocab answers do?

Comment: @Droogans: Absolutely not! Each row contains *one* question id, and *one* answer. Where a question has multiple answers, there will be multiple entries the answer table for that question.

Comment: I think you've successfully changed the way im thinking about this. A `1:n` cardinality was not in my initial design. +1

Comment: I gave you the accepted answer, but only time will tell if your suggestion pans out. It seems good...but database design questions are hard. There's never any way to find out unless you just *do it*. Thanks!